# any documentation on tpcc-mysql benchmark tool

Tags: mysql, percona, percona-tools, percona-server, benchmark

Where can I find tpcc-mysql documentation? I google it but I can't find any documentation about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I searched around Google, and I'll admit, it's tough to find any documentation.

You can try these links

- [Download Site](https://code.launchpad.net/~percona-dev/perconatools/tpcc-mysql)
- [Clustrix tpcc-mysql Benchmark](http://www.percona.com/about-us/mysql-white-paper/clustrix-tpcc-mysql-benchmark)
- [Full Search within Percona's Website](http://search.percona.com/search/tpcc)

I also recommend reading the `README` file when you download and install it. Perhaps the `README` file will give you some guidance on getting proper documentation.

Answer (score 4):

Here's a recent blog post (2013-07-01) that shows how to use tpcc-mysql and graph results:

http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2013/07/01/tpcc-mysql-simple-usage-steps-and-how-to-build-graphs-with-gnuplot/

This is written by Michael Rikmas, who is a super nice guy, and a long time Percona support engineer.